# Entity relationship diagram fixed attribute of an attribute

Tags: entity-relationship

I may not have a full understanding of this, but this confuses me some.

I need to create a database of a bank with accounts, customers, loans and branches, I've done all of that it's just I'm not sure how to represent the types of account.
I am told there are 3 types of account - Student, Current and Saver and they each have their own interest rates. But I don't know how to draw it out.

[image: Here's my idea, but I'm not sure if it's right]

Is this right? Is there a better way to do it, or is it wrong.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it is that table accounts will have columns for type_of_account and int_rate and table customers will have all the customer details.

You can then place an intersection entity between accounts and customers because of the many-to-many relationship linking the customer to the type of account they have with foreign key constraints in the new intersection entity.